# Input arguments zkQuorum and group to be passed to Kafkautils.createStream method

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to execute the below code which Pulls the messages from Kafka Producer and does the word count.

This code is from the Github.     https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala

```
object KafkaWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 4) {
      System.err.println("Usage: KafkaWordCount <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()
    val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

    val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L))
      .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)
    wordCounts.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

My Question is: I have started the kafka zookeeper and server(broker) and also created a topic with name "Mytopic1".
The code is expecting these 4 arguments: zkQuorum,group,topics,numThreads.
I know I can pass "Mytopic1", "1" as arguments for topics and numthreads. But for zkQuorum and group what will be the values to pass to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `zkQuorum` is a comma-separated list of Zookeper URIs, like `your.host.name:2181`
- `group` is an arbitrary group name you want to use for your consumer group.

Comment: how do I create consumer group ?    I started the consumer in windows command prompt using the below command. So what will be the consumer group for me to use as a argument ?                                          
Command: "kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic Mytopic1 --from-beginning"

Comment: fyi I am able to send messages from the topic "Mytopic1" through command prompt and am able to receive messages by consumer at my command prompt. But my requirement is as I said, I want my Spark application to read the messages from the Kafka topic by passing the required arguments. Got stuck over here. Can you please help in this regard.